# How to fix missing / flickering images in w3m?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, w3m

I use w3m to browse websites inside a shell, e.g.

```
w3m https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Valued_images
```

w3m supports displaying images the rendering seems buggy. They sometimes won't show at all, or will flicker when scrolling.

This is an example of the problematic output:

[image: gif animation of the image rendering problem in w3m, not showing the image, and having them flicker during scroll]

I am using terminator, yet also could reproduce the behavior using konsole and terminal.

Comment: I've exactly same issue- I've used xterm, gonme-terminal, urxvt

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be an issue with anti-aliasing.

After I disabled anti-aliasing in my xresources the flickering went away.

Of course, now the font rendering is ugly, but it showcases that `w3m` is having issues with font rendering when it comes to anti-aliasing.

The following is an example of how the disable anti aliasing in the .Xresources:

```
Xft.antialias: 0
```

Comment: Can you please explicate on how you disabled the anti-aliasing?

Comment: updated the post